# dash app refusing to start: '127.0.0.1 refused to connect.'

Tags: python, dashboard, plotly-dash

I am trying to run the example dash application but upon trying to run, the browser says it is refusing to connect. I have checked and Google Chrome has access through the firewall.

The example code is:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

html.Div(children='''
    Dash: A web application framework for Python.
'''),

dcc.Graph(
    id='example-graph',
    figure={
        'data': [
            {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
            {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
        ],
        'layout': {
            'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
        }
    }
)
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Here is a picture of my browser:

[image]

Does anyone understand this?

Comment: Try using a different port

Comment: @Teedeez Changing the port made no difference

Comment: Could be that server is not running, use `netstat` command or similar tool to check for bound addresses

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First check if you are accessing the right port, the default one (usually) is 8050: http://localhost:8050/

Also, check if there is another Dash code running, it might be occupying the port.

If it does not work, try determining the host as an argument in app.runserver(args), like this:

```
app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

You might also want to determine the port as an argument like this:

```
app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port=8050, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
app.run_server(debug=True)
```

to

```
app.run_server(debug=False)
```

and then try.

Comment: Why would removing debugging info help in this situation?

Comment: I found this workout while browsing through the official Dash support threads. Setting debugging True doesn't allow to render the Dash application. I already posted question on Dash thread to get information about this problem. I will add it here whenever I heard back anything from them.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue. I was running Jupyter Lab in a container on a remote server. I can't offer specific code because I don't know your configuration, but for me this involved forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8050 to port 8050 on the container.

Hopefully this can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and discovered I forgot to launch the app by running
`python app.py`
before visiting my browser. (Assuming your file is named `app.py`). Once I did this, all was well.

https://dash.plotly.com/layout shows how to do this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I did this change:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='localhost',port=8005)
```

And the code worked fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

Was experiencing the same issue and setting "debug=False" definitely was not a solution as "debug=True" is a part of the tutorial to show the "hot-reloading" functionality (see https://dash.plotly.com/layout).

Looked a bit and from the site below I noticed "alitarraf" mentioning that python could get stuck on an old version:
https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/108

After seeing that I killed "python.exe" in the details tab of task manager.
This resolved the issue for me.

Edit:
After a reboot it seems like the issue also is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I was launching the app in the console (in Rstudio IDE), try to use the terminal, with the good python interpreter `python3 app.py`

And changing the port could help if the default one is already taken.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port=8007, debug=False)
```